# `override init(frame: CGRect)` never called?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a simple UIView subclass that looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class AngleViewManager: UIView {

    class AngleView: UIView {
        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }


        init(first: CGPoint, second: CGPoint, third: CGPoint) {
            // setup
            super.init(frame: CGRect(dimensions))
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
}
```

When I initialize an `AngleView` instance within `AngleViewManager` like

`AngleView(firstPoint, secondPoint, thirdPoint)`,

the background color is not red, and setting a breakpoint in the overridden init shows that it is never called even though I am explicitly calling it in my custom initializer which does get called successfully.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: `Am I missing something obvious?` -> Yes, yes you are :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the super class's (`UIView`) implementation of `init(frame: CGRect)`.

Just change it to `self.init(frame: frame)`

Comment: This will require it to be a `convenience` initializer.

Comment: How would I access instance variables before the instance is initialized if I changed it to a `convenience` initializer + called `self.init`?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa You put `super.init(frame: CGRect(dimensions))` prior to `// setup`

Comment: *facepalm* Sorry, I'm not fully awake yet I guess. Thank you for answering my embarrassingly trivial question.